# HTML Validator shows an error on a seemingly correct line of code

Tags: html, validation

I am creating a table for an university task. Every once in a while we have to put our code into a validator. For some reason the validator keeps showing these errors:
https://i.ibb.co/dLnzTh2/error.png

The errors are about the `<th>` tag inside the `<thead>`.

```
<table style="width: 700px" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="8">Market Shares of Graphics Adapters in Q4 2013
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">-</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Q4 2013</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Q3 2013</td>
                    <td colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center">Quarter over Quarter Changes</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">2012</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Unit Shipments</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Share</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AMD</td>
                    <td>18.30%</td>
                    <td>20.70%</td>
                    <td colspan="2">-10.40%</td>
                    <td colspan="2">-2.40%</td>
                    <td>19.70%</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas what is causing this?
For reference this is how the whole table looks like:
https://i.ibb.co/LkMbWc9/table.png

Comment: Would help to know what validator you are using and what happens when you validate a known correct table structure like that found here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This always means "a column without any cells" - harder to find with collspans, but possible - in the snippet `Unit Shipments` and `Share` are blue - this are doubled td, and it makes an empty column in both - since both are colspaned from the top.
Shortly - whole table is too wide of 2 not needed cells

```css
td, th{ border: 1px solid red}          /* this shows every th, td even empty */
td[colspan] { border: 1px solid blue}       /* this shows colspans */
```

```html
<table style="width: 700px" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="8">Market Shares of Graphics Adapters in Q4 2013
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">-</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Q4 2013</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Q3 2013</td>
                    <td colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center">Quarter over Quarter Changes</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">2012</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Unit Shipments</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Share</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AMD</td>
                    <td>18.30%</td>
                    <td>20.70%</td>
                    <td colspan="2">-10.40%</td>
                    <td colspan="2">-2.40%</td>
                    <td>19.70%</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```